# Pivot without Aggregation-Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have used power query from previous post, to convert JSON array to `PowerBI` data.
Pivoting a column is throwing error on transformation

> Error: Expression.Error: There were too many elements in the
>   enumeration to complete the operation. Details:   List

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Type": "Workers",
      "Values": [
        "Manager",
        "Delegate",
        "Authority"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Type": "WorkCode",
      "Values": [
        "134",
        "135",
        "140",
        "141",
        "142",
        "143",
        "150"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Type": "Place",
      "Values": [
        "UK",
        "Europe"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Workers      WorkCode    Place
-----------------------
Manager       134         UK
delegate      135         Europe 
Authority     etc
```

Query:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://127.0.0.1:8083/api/v1/rthb-e-powerBI-client-login-report/refData")),
   #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"Type", "Values"}, {"Value.Type", "Value.Values"}),
    #"Expanded Value.Values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value1", "Value.Values"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Value.Values",{"Name"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Appreciate any inputs

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @JelleHoekstra I have added error description to the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relationship between "Workers", "WorkCode" and "Place" in the JSON file specified, thus the error. 
One can assume that a specific worker code belongs to a specific worker based on position.

To get the desired result in Power Bi the relationship needs to be established between Workers their codes and places. It can be done as follows:

1) Add an Index column (say "Index")
[image]

2) Group rows by Workers [image]

3) Add another index column (subindex)

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "subindex", each Table.AddIndexColumn([codes], "wcode", 1,1))
```

4) Can remove unwanted column ("codes" in this example), now

5) Expand "Subindex" column [image]

6) Now, columns "colname", "subindex.Index" can be removed. And the final result should be similar to this one [image]

7) Pivot the table [image]

Here is the complete Power Query code

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("<<PATH TO YOUR JSON FILE>>")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"Type", "Values"}, {"Value.Type", "Value.Values"}),
    #"Expanded Value.Values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value1", "Value.Values"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Value.Values",{{"Value.Type", "colname"}, {"Value.Values", "colvalue"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Name"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"colname"}, {{"codes", each _, type table [colname=text, colvalue=text, Index=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "subindex", each Table.AddIndexColumn([codes], "wcode", 1,1)),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"codes"}),
    #"Expanded subindex" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "subindex", {"colname", "colvalue", "Index", "wcode"}, {"subindex.colname", "subindex.colvalue", "subindex.Index", "subindex.wcode"}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded subindex",{"colname", "subindex.Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns2", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns2"[subindex.colname]), "subindex.colname", "subindex.colvalue")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```